# Count number of rows inserted in a table for every one hour

Tags: sql

I faced a problem to getting the count of records for every one hour.

my table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `statistics` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `uuid` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `type_id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `in_time` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `out_time` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `error_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=1594;
```

I tried a query like this:

```
SELECT FLOOR( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( NOW(), last_updated)) / 3600 ) HOURS,COUNT(*),error_id FROM statistics WHERE last_updated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) GROUP BY HOUR(last_updated) and error_id != 0 ORDER BY last_updated DESC;
```

output is like this

```
+-------+----------+
| HOURS | COUNT(*) |
+-------+----------+
|     1 |      205 | 
|     2 |       70 | 
|     3 |       14 | 
|     4 |       10 | 
|     5 |       16 | 
|     7 |       29 | 
|     8 |      412 | 
|     9 |       65 | 
|    10 |       79 | 
|    11 |      149 | 
|    12 |      317 | 
|    13 |      306 | 
|    14 |      356 | 
|    15 |      597 | 
|    16 |      433 | 
|    17 |      186 | 
|    18 |      527 | 
|    19 |      349 | 
|    20 |      397 | 
|    21 |      480 | 
|    22 |      460 | 
|    23 |      526 | 
|    23 |      411 | 
+-------+----------+
```

but it is not correct. because same hours(23) are different counts.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the same thing that you're calculating - ie : `FLOOR( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( NOW(), last_updated)) / 3600 )`

Currently, you're calculating one thing, yet grouping by another.